# Replace old print function in python with new one in sublime text

Tags: replace, sublimetext3

So I found a script on github that i wanted to use but the problem was that it was written using an older version of python therefore the printing function was written as `print 'Hello World!'` instead of `print('Hello World!')` and I coulnd't execute it, so I wanted to know if there's a way of replacing every line of the script that has the old python function with the new one using sublime text 3. I thought of trying:

`Find: print '(.*)'` - to select every print function which it works but when I try to replace it with

`Replace: print("(.*)")` - it simply replaces what's inside of the print function with (.*) instead of the actual content

Comment: You might want to consider using `2to3` https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Comment: In general, though, for regex find and replace you'll need a token like `\1` to include the match in the substitution. E.g. https://regex101.com/r/rIem68/1

Answer (score 1):

**Using Sublime:**
**Find:** `print ('.*')`
**Replace:** `print\(\1\)`

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]